# Highlight Code Block Backgrounds with Vim

Tags: php, vim, syntax-highlighting, codeblocks

While I am working in Vim I'd like to have a slight background color change for all code inside the php tags. So for example, the background is solid black for regular XHTML markup, then displays slighly lighter inside the php tags to help me identify it quickly. Is this something I can/should do with the color scheme or is there another method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in the color scheme

example:

```
hi htmlTag          guifg=#00bdec   guibg=#200000            gui=bold
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not too familiar with vim colorschemes. Is there a way to do this with 256 color console mode as opposed to gui? I'm using a 256 color theme (xterm16.vim)

Comment: Just use ctermfg / ctermbg / cterm instead of guifg / guibg / gui

Comment: Thank you, this looks much nicer now!

Comment: @modethirteen what does it look like for you? For me it highlights bizarre parts of my code like `<`, `>` and `=`